# Raspberry Pi SSH Not Working

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to SSH into my raspberry pi from my windows machine, and the terminal environment WAS working fine, but the GUI is acting really crappy. There is no Xming window that opens up when Xming starts (but it is running according to the task manager). The taskbar in Raspbian doesn't move around (and covers up the windows taskbar), and there is a bunch of little glitches with the desktop.  My motors are also being weird: when I turn on my Pi one of them starts moving.  The same thing happens when I turn off my Pi (but not the H-Bridge Board).  Everything (including the motors) work perfectly fine when I use my Pi with a TV via HDMI. I have the model 2 Raspberry Pi running Raspbian, Windows 10 on my computer, and am using Putty. I'm pretty new to this, so I will appreciate any help.

Comment: What model of the raspberry pi do you have?

Comment: I have the model B (of the second generation).  The Pi 2

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the GUI? If not, I would suggest turning off X11 forwarding in putty (Connection - SSH - X11) and just using the console.

Comment: I do need the gui for one program, but I could modify it for the console (I think).  I guese it would be good practice, since I'm not very comfortable with the Linux Kernel.